# How to pass event to setAttribute function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a function which creates circles that are appended to an svg element. I want the function `selectCircle(event)` to be triggered when the circle is selected.

```
function addObjects() {
  var demoSVG = document.getElementById("demoSVG");
  demoSVG.appendChild(createCircle(10, 10, 10, 1));
}
function createCircle(startPercent, diffPercent, rPercent, i) {
  var obj = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  obj.setAttribute("id", "obj" + i);
  obj.setAttribute("class", "draggable");
  obj.setAttribute("cx", startPercent + i * diffPercent + "%");
  obj.setAttribute("cy", "90%");
  obj.setAttribute("r", rPercent + "%");
  obj.setAttribute("onmousedown", "selectCircle(event)");
  return obj;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox. I get a `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. I understand that it does not see `event` but can't seem to figure out how to fix it because `createCircle()` does not have an event associated to it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the event handler is defined when you're creating the circle:

```
obj.addEventListener("mousedown", selectCircle);
```

It seems that maybe FF doesn't wrap attribute-based event handlers for SVG elements the same way that it does for [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value). (The MDN documentation does explicitly say "**HTML** attribute".)